# Destructive reject from an array returning the values rejected

Tags: arrays, ruby

Is there a sensible way to do the following:

I want to take an array and select specific items from the array according to conditions, removing them from the array as they go. 
(I basically want to split the contents of an array into categories).

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

less_than_three = array.reject_destructively{|v| v<3}
=> [1,2]
array
=> [3,4,5,6,7,8]
more_than_five = array.reject_destructively{|v| v>5}
=> [6,7,8]
array
=> [3,4,5]
```

I've tried delete_if, select!, reject! and none of them seem to be able to give you the affected items whilst leaving the array with the rest. 
Unless I'm going mad, which is entirely possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build  your own method for this...

```
class Array
  def extract(&block)
    temp = self.select(&block)
    self.reject!(&block)
    temp
  end
end
```

then...

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.extract{|x| x < 3}
=> [1,2]
p a
=> [3, 4, 5]
```

EDIT: If you don't want to monkey patch (but monkey patching isn't evil in itself) you can do it with a vanilla method...

```
def select_from_array(array, &block)
   temp = array.select(&block)
   array.reject!(&block)
   temp
end

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

less_than_three = select_from_array(array){|v| v<3}
=> [1,2]
array
=> [3,4,5,6,7,8]
more_than_five = select_from_array(array){|v| v>5}
=> [6,7,8]
array
=> [3,4,5]
```

Comment: Would rather avoid monkey-patching if I can... This looks like it does exactly what's required, but I just know I'll break something and forget what I did....

Answer (score 8):

As I understood the question, you do not want to produce two new objects. Here you go:

```
class Array
  def carve!
    dup.tap { delete_if &Proc.new } - self
  end
end

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
p array.carve! { |v| v < 3 }
#⇒ [1, 2]                   # returned by Array#carve method
p array
#⇒ [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]       # remained in original array
```

Using this solution, `array.__id__` remains the same. And this is the golfiest answer all around :)

Answer (score 5):

In rails 6 there is a method `extract!`:

```rb
a = [1, 2, 3] #=> [1, 2, 3]

a.extract! { |num| num.odd? } #=> [1, 3]

a #=> [2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
irb(main):001:0> array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
irb(main):002:0> array.partition{|v| v < 3}
=> [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

is there a specific reason, why this has to be `destructive` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This works, avoids monkey patching, keeps it to one line...etc, but it's damn ugly....

```
less_than_three = array.dup - array.reject!{|v| v<3}
=> [1,2]
array
=> [3,4,5,6,7,8]
more_than_five = array.dup - array.reject!{|v| v>5}
=> [6,7,8]
array
=> [3,4,5]
```

Comment: What is the problem with monkeypatching?

Comment: Nothing, if you know what you're doing, I guess. I'm just always a little wary of it...

Answer (score 0):

Will this help

```
class Array 
    def reject_destructively(&block)
        arr = self.select(&block)
        arr.each{ |i| self.delete(i) }
        arr
    end
end

array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
p less_than_three = array.reject_destructively{|v| v<3}
#=> [1,2]
p array
#=> [3,4,5,6,7,8]
p more_than_five = array.reject_destructively{|v| v>5}
#=> [6,7,8]
p array
#=> [3,4,5]
```

The above code can be simplified further to look like:

```
class Array 
    def reject_destructively(&block)
        self.select(&block).each{ |i| self.delete(i) }
    end
end
```

Comment: that has the same issue. less than three then returns [3,4,5,6,7,8] (which is, of course, exactly the opposite of what we need)

Comment: Okay updated answer - I am using monkey patching though

Answer (score 0):

```
module Enumerable
    def reject_destructively
        array=[]
        self.each do |y|
            if yield(y)
                array<<y
            end
        end
        array.each do |x|
            self.delete(x)
        end
        return array
    end
end
array=[10,9,2,1,3,45,52]
print less_than_three = array.reject_destructively{|v| v < 3}
print array
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `group_by` to get all of the elements that satisfy the condition in one group, and all of the rest in the other.
For example

```
[1,2,3,4,5].group_by{|i| i > 3}
```

gives

```
{false=>[1, 2, 3], true=>[4, 5]}
```

More information is available at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: MAybe there isn't a good way to do this, but I need to extract the first 'group' from the array before I extract a later group, since there are some items that would be shared members that I only want to be in the first group....

Comment: That's exactly what's partition is for: `(1..6).partition { |v| v.even? }  #=> [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]`

Comment: Thanks for that axel, I wasn't aware of that function, but it is much simpler in this case.